# webpack DefinePlugin use external config.js

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller, webpack

I am new in webpack
I have this code in webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var pkg = require('./package.json');
var myconfig = require('./webpack.myconfig.js');

// bundle dependencies in separate vendor bundle
var dependencies = Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).filter(function (el) {
  //exclude font packages from vendor bundle & css-toggle-switch
  if (el.indexOf('font') !== -1 || el.indexOf('css-toggle-switch') !== -1) {
    return false;
  }
  else return true;
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
      libs: dependencies,
      main: './src/index'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, myconfig.buildPath),
    publicPath: myconfig.uiURL, 
    filename: 'dist/js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      DEBUG_MODE: JSON.stringify(false),
      TIMEOUT: JSON.stringify(30000),
      API_URL: JSON.stringify(myconfig.apiUrl),
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'libs',
      filename: 'dist/js/libs.js',
      minChunks: Infinity
    })
  ],
};
```

and this is myconfig.js

```
myconfig = {
  uiURL: 'http://example.com/',
  apiUrl: 'http://api.example.com/api/'
};

module.exports = myconfig;
```

and if I run this syntax

```
webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors
```

I will get the result like

```
/dist/js/libs.js
/dist/js/main.js
```

but I want the result not like this, I want the result to be:

```
/dist/js/myconfig.js
/dist/js/libs.js
/dist/js/main.js
```

What really I want is,
I want in main.js file, it will use myconfig.apiUrl as depedencies, 
so when I deployed to production or qserver, I just change myconfig.js.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`webpack.myconfig.js` is used in webpack config file so you have to rebuild every time when `webpack.myconfig.js` is changed.

You could use myconfig.json and send http request to get it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get `myconfig.js` in `/dist/js/`, you can use `CopyWebpackPlugin`. It can copy static files from one path to another.

Add a new new line `plugins` section like :

```
 plugins: [
     new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: APP_DIR + '\\images', to: APP_DIR + '\\build\\images' }]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      DEBUG_MODE: JSON.stringify(false),
      TIMEOUT: JSON.stringify(30000),
      API_URL: JSON.stringify(myconfig.apiUrl),
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'libs',
      filename: 'dist/js/libs.js',
      minChunks: Infinity
    })
  ],
```

Here `CopyWebpackPlugin` copies file from one path to another.

Make sure you `var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');`at top of `webpack.config.js` & added same in `package.json` & installed via `npm`.